# How to remap the keys with xkeycaps?

Tags: fedora, kde, keyboard

I'm trying to remap different keys (for example, I want the "Y" to be "space"). XKeyCaps let me choose the keyboard, and shows correctly when one key is pressed. But the right click menu that allows to do the changes shows up but doesn't work (it stays up as long as the right mouse button is clicked, options are not grayed, but nothing can be selected).

I'm using Fedora 20 with KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be resolved by deactivating Num- or Caps-Lock, as is stated in the [XKeyCaps manual](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/man.html):

> "If you can't select anything from the right-button popup menu, it
>   might be because you have NumLock or CapsLock down. I'm not sure how
>   to fix this, it seems to be some dumb Xt thing."

Alternatively:

> "If the popup menu is always greyed out, or doesn't correspond to the key that you clicked on, it might be because you're running xswarm, an old version of xautolock, or some other program that antisocially interferes with event-propagation. (Don't go like that.)"